# Are there any major Esperanto translation projects for either open source software or moddable games?

Tags: translation

Once I'm better at the language, I'd like to contribute to something like this- it'd be nice to play Skyrim in Esperanto for example.

Answer (score 7):

I am using Debian Linux in Esperanto, and a large part of the interface is translated.  There was for a long time resistance in some parts of the Linux world to Esperanto, so it seems it was only this year that the Esperanto localization was made official in the libc, the basic library in Linux, although some distributions such as Debian and Ubuntu had Esperanto for a long time.

You can join the Esperanto translation team for example for GNOME at https://l10n.gnome.org/teams/eo/.  Other projects will have similar coordination efforts.

Comment: The translation projects for [MATE](https://www.transifex.com/mate/MATE/dashboard/) and [Xfce](https://www.transifex.com/xfce/) can be found on Transifex. They are at 49% and 30%, respectively.

Comment: I've referenced this answer in another question. http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/2119/how-has-linux-geek-culture-reacted-to-esperanto-over-the-years

Answer (score 6):

There are many websites for crowd-translating various programs. Two of the biggest are: [Transifex](http://transifex.com/) kaj [Crowdin](https://crowdin.com/). You can look around and see if anything is of interest of you, then see if there is an Esperanto translation already started. You can help for anything you like, and many of the projects already have some progress in Esperanto but there aren't much that have reached 100%.

- For games, I personally know that ["Mini Metro"](http://store.steampowered.com/app/287980/), ["Teeworlds"](https://www.teeworlds.com/) and ["Minecraft"](https://minecraft.net) have been translated 100% to Esperanto but there are many more that have some progress. But nothing AAA so far.
- For other kinds of software, there are many, many things that have at least to some extent been translated to Esperanto.

Try looking for you favourite (open source or not) software in those two systems. If it is not there and (you know) it is crowd-translated, it most likely has its own translation system, that should be found on their own web site.

---

Ekzistas multe da retejoj por amastraduko de diversaj programoj. Du el la plej grandaj estas: [Transifex](http://transifex.com/) kaj [Crowdin](https://crowdin.com/). Vi povas enrigardi kaj trovi ion interesan por vi, kaj poste kontroli ĉu estas jam komencita Esperanta traduko. Vi povas helpi pri ĉiu, kiun vin interesas, kaj multaj projektoj jam havas iom da Esperanta progreso, sed malmulte estas kompletaj.

- Pri ludoj: persone mi scias, ke [„Mini Metro“](http://store.steampowered.com/app/287980/), [„Teeworlds“](https://www.teeworlds.com/) kaj [„Minecraft“](https://minecraft.net) estas tradukitaj je 100% al Esperanto, sed estas multaj, kiuj havas iom da progreso. Sed mi pensas, ke niniu *granda* ludo havas Esperantan tradukon;
- Pri aliaj programoj: estas multege da programoj, kiuj havas almenaŭ ia Esperantan tradukon.

Vi povas serĉi vian plej ŝatatan (liberkoda aŭ ne) programaron en la du sistemoj. Se ĝi ne troviĝas tie, kaj (vi scias, ke) ĝi povas esti tradukata el la komunumo, plej verŝajne ĝi havas sian propran traduksistemon, kiun oni povus trovi en la programa retejo.

Answer (score 3):

There is a project for translating CyanogenMod https://crowdin.com/project/cyanogenmod/eo. Beyond Crowdin and Transifex, also check out Weblate and Translatewiki

Answer (score 2):

Roundcube, an email client, has a translation to Esperanto, which needs maintenance. Facebook too

Answer (score 0):

You could help translate for Wordpress or Openshot.